# Using eval() function on class methods

Tags: python

I m trying to solve a [hackerrank challenge](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/string-validators/):

> **Sample Input**
>
> ```
> S = "qA2"
> ```
>
> In the first line, print `True` if S has any alphanumeric characters. Otherwise, print `False`.
>   In the second line, print `True` if S has any alphabetical characters. Otherwise, print `False`.
>   In the third line, print `True` if S has any digits. Otherwise, print `False`.
>   In the fourth line, print `True` if S has any lowercase characters. Otherwise, print `False`.
>   In the fifth line, print `True` if S has any uppercase characters. Otherwise, print `False`.

I know there are simpler way to do it but I d like to use `eval()`.
Rather than having multiple line with all the methods, I wanted to use a list with the methods in it (cmd here) then go through it with a for loop, and the `eval()` should transform it to a method (`eval(i+"."+j)`). If any of the character `i` in `list(s)` returns True, it print true.

Code/Attempt:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = input()
    cmd=["isalnum()","isalpha()"]
    for j in cmd:
        print (any([eval(i+"."+j) for i in list(s)]))
```

Traceback/Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Solution.py", line 5, in <module>
    print (any([eval(i+"."+j) for i in list(s)]))
  File "Solution.py", line 5, in <listcomp>
    print (any([eval(i+"."+j) for i in list(s)]))
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'q' is not defined
```

Comment: Why would you do that? Why use strings and not the functions themselves?

Comment: cauz I want to make the function iterable rather than copy past, I have only 5 methods to apply here. what if I have 100?

Comment: You still don't have to do it this way. That's why I said, *use the functions themselves*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is having an issue because when your strings are concatenated in the `eval()` statement you get something resembling `q.isalnum()` when you really want `'q'.isalnum()`. The first one is using `q` like a variable when you really want to call the method on the character `'q'`. Something like this:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = input()
    cmd=["isalnum()","isalpha()"]
    for j in cmd:
        print (any([eval("'{}'.{}".format(i, j)) for i in list(s)]))
```

Instead of using strings as commands, you could just use the function itself:

```py
cmd=[str.isalnum, str.isalpha]
```

and then you wouldn't need to use eval as it would just be:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = input()
    cmd=[str.isalnum,str.isalpha]
    for j in cmd:
        print (any([j(i) for i in list(s)]))
```

### Edit:

For the sake of completeness, you could also remove the brackets inside the `any()` to create a generator rather than a list comprehension. This is good because the generator will stop once it first reaches the first `True` result whereas a list comprehension will evaluate for the whole string. You also don't need to convert `s` into a list as strings are iterable on their own. You're then left with:

```py
any(j(i) for i in s)
```

Comment: why to do such effort if there is easy way of copy paste 5 times?

Comment: Because this way is more expandable and dynamic. It may be overkill for the 5 cases that were in the original problem but with this you can reorder the functions and have 100's if not 1000's of different tests without having to change the underlying logic. If you copy paste 1000 times, now you have code that is very hard to manage in the long run because the same thing is repeated over and over.

Comment: that s awesome! super neat code now.how would you explain the str in the str.isalpha? is it correct if I say: 'example'.isalpha() = str.isalpha(example)

Comment: Yeah, `'example'.isalpha()` actually just gets translated to `str.isalpha('example')`. The first one is just syntactic sugar for the second and in this case `str` is the class of `'example'`. In my example, it was easier to use the `str.isalpha` because I could then pass the string as a parameter rather than having to build up a function call.

Comment: It's actually not *merely* syntactic sugar, but the effect is the same.

Comment: Ah, I guess I had always assumed it was. But now that you say it, _just_ being syntactic sugar would cause issues when doing something like `fn = obj.method` and then later calling `fn()` because `obj` needs to be bound to `fn` for later use.